# CSS Bold every Nth

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a grid overlay in a D3 visualization.  I'm wondering if there is a way to bold every Nth vertical line.

Here's the CSS I currently have

```
.axis path,
.axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}

.line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
}

.tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

How do I bold, or set the width n pixels wider every 3rd line?

Comment: Can you show the HTML (or, what is it, SVG?) as well.

Comment: With css maybe you can use selectors like `:nth-child` but without see the HTML structure we can't help you.